# Haskell issue with tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I made a function in Haskell where I have a list of tuples, and want to extract only the second value of each tuple and return a list of the second values of the tuples.. I wrote this function but i get a weird error..

```
   --converts a list of tuples to single list
tupleToList :: [Stat] -> [Int]
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) =  b : tupleToList xs
```

I get an error on the ':' after(a,b) in the second line. Any ideas what might be causing the problem? The function itself doesn't appear wrong to me but I'm new to Haskell so maybe there's something I'm not following right.

Comment: by the way,'Stat' is a type which is a tuple of the form : (String,Int)

Comment: "I get an error" - what error? The code seem fine to me as well. Maybe include a minimum working example (including imports, type defintions, etc).

Comment: it's a parse error on input':'

Comment: what you have is working here so the error is probably somewhere else in your file - btw: it seems as if you only want `tupleToList = map snd` anyway

Comment: @HassanAli There is no parse error in the code you posted. Again, please include a minimum working example.

Comment: I second the use of `map snd `. Your version doesn't handle empty list so it'll error out eventually.

Comment: so how do i rewrite the function ? :/

Answer (score 1):

As others said there doesn't seem to be any error in what you wrote (other than what I noticed: you don't handle the case of an empty list.)

You asked in the comments how to rewrite it.

The simplest way is to do what Carsten said

```
tupleToList = map snd
```

If for some reason you wanted to build on your own version.

```
tupleToList :: [Stat] -> [Int]
tupleToList [] = []
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) =  b : tupleToList xs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this extremely simply like this:

```
tupleToList = map snd
```

result:

```
> tupleToList [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")]
["a","b","c"]
```